# Get the associated name of two database columns of the same type

Tags: sql

My schema is as follows:

- The `airports` table holds airport names. It's primary key is an integer, `id`.
- The `flights` table holds flight data. It has two foreign keys, `departure_airport_id` and `arrival_airport_id`

I am trying to get the names of both the departure- and arrival airport on a flight. Right now my SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT name AS departure_airport, name AS arrival_airport FROM flights, airports WHERE departure_airport_id = airports.id OR arrival_airport_id = airports.id
```

I can see how this is ambiguous since the database can't know that by `departure_airport` I mean the name of `departure_airport_id` and by `arrival_airport` I mean the name of 'arrival_airport_id', but what is the correct way to get the names of both airports on a flight record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN twice from flights onto the airports table, like so:

```
SELECT dep.name AS departure_airport, arr.name AS arrival_airport 
FROM flights f
    JOIN airports dep ON f.departure_airport_id = dep.id 
    JOIN airports arr ON f.arrival_airport_id = arr.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT departure_airport.name AS departure_airport, 
           arrival_airport.name AS arrival_airport 
      FROM flights
INNER JOIN airports departure_airport
        ON departure_airport.id = flights.departure_airport_id
INNER JOIN airports arrival_airport
        ON arrival_airport.id = flights.arrival_airport_id
```

There's no problem joining to a table more than once if you use a different alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT depart.name AS departure_airport, arr.name AS arrival_airport 
FROM flights, airports arr,airports depart 
WHERE departure_airport_id = depart.id and
arrival_airport_id = arr.id
```